# How do I Check If a Particular App Is Installed using Flutter on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How do I Check If a Particular App Is Installed using Flutter on iOS?

Let's say if I want to check if the user have Telegram installed. How to go about it?

Thank you

Comment: Refer: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appavailability

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't allow to get installed apps. For Android you can use [device_app](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps)